# É possivel gerar um arquivo .CSV a partir de uma tabela de um banco de dados Firebird

Tags: firebird, csv

Preciso Gerar um arquivo `.CSV` de uma tabela da minha base de dados Firebird, há alguma ferramenta conhecida que poderia me auxiliar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Praticamente toda ferramenta administrativa exporta. Por exemplo, o [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/fbexport.html) pode fazer isso.